Undefined class 'TextEditingController'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class,
i`m new flutter dev and iam trying to make login page with laravel and roles for login this is my login coe and main file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/coordinator_orders_page.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/delivery_orders_page.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/manager_orders_page.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/seller_orders_page.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/data_entry_orders_page.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/pages/insert_order_form_page.dart'
    as insertOrder;

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final AuthService authService = AuthService();
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void login() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final response = await authService.login(
        emailController.text,
        passwordController.text,
      );

      final role = response['user']['role']['name'];
      Widget nextPage;

      switch (role) {
        case 'data_entry':
          nextPage = insertOrder.InsertOrderFormPage();
          break;
        case 'coordinator':
          nextPage = CoordinatorOrdersPage();
          break;
        case 'delivery':
          nextPage = DeliveryOrdersPage();
          break;
        case 'manager':
          nextPage = ManagerOrdersPage();
          break;
        case 'seller':
          nextPage = SellerOrdersPage();
          break;
        default:
          nextPage = DataEntryOrdersPage();
      }

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => nextPage),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Failed to login. Please check your credentials.'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        ),
      );
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextField(
              controller: passwordController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            isLoading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: login,
                    child: Text('Login'),
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mtg_shipping_frontend/login_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MTG Shipping',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}


i checked on flutter doctor and it was clear and i tried upgrade flutter but no change
and i tried
flutter clean
flutter pub get
same error there and gpt not solving it or even found any problem like this
